# Batch para localizar uma subpasta, mover todos os arquivos para um nível acima e deletar a pasta

Tags: batch, cmd

Tenho esta estrutura:

```
    ..
    ..\FolderA\FolderX\File1.txt
    ..\FolderB\FolderX\File2.txt
    ..\FolderC\FolderD\FolderE\FolderX\File3.txt
```

Eu preciso de um batch que localize todas as pastas "FolderX" nos subdiretórios e mova todos os arquivos para um nível acima e delete a pasta "FolderX"

```
    ..
    ..\FolderA\File1.txt
    ..\FolderB\File2.txt
    ..\FolderC\FolderD\FolderE\File3.txt
```

Como programar o batch? Eu tentei este código, mas está incompleto, pois não localiza as pastas.

```
    @Echo Off
    Set _Source=%~dp0
    Set _FindDir=FolderX
    Set _Path=%_Source%\%_FindDir%
    If Exist "%_Path%" (
    Move /-Y "%_Path%\*.*" "%_Source%"
    For /F "Tokens=* Delims=" %%I In ('Dir /AD /B "%_Path%"') Do Move "%_Path%\%%I" "%_Source%"
    RD /S /Q "%_Path%"
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido com o seguinte código:

```
    @echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for /d /r %~dp0 %%a in (*) do (
    if /i "%%~nxa"=="FolderX" (
    set "folderpath=%%a" (
    move /y !folderpath!\* !folderpath:~,-8!
    rmdir !folderpath!
    )
    )
    )
```